# WPF application use the wrong language for formatting DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, culture

I'm working on a WPF application using Visual Studio 2015, installed in french but I'm using the english language pack. I have a french Windows 10, a french keyboard layout and the Windows region is Canada. In my application, I explicitely set the culture to be 'en-CA' using the following code in Application_Startup:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-CA");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

Then, following an answer on SO, in my main windows' constructor I do:

```
this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("en-CA");
```

In a listview, I display an object using it's DisplayString property, which is:

```
return Start.ToString("dd MMM") // Start is a DateTime
```

The listview is defined as

```
<ListView x:Name="lvEntries" Margin="435,81,10,5" SelectionChanged="lvEntries_SelectionChanged" 
      SelectionMode="Single" MaxHeight="516" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="412" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Consolas" >
<ListView.View>
    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
        <GridViewColumn Header="Period" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DisplayString}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Project" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProjectName}" />
    </GridView>
</ListView.View></ListView>
```

Everything works fine when the application starts, but after any button click, the formatting of the DateTime use the french abbreviation for months.
Ex: **Before : '14 Dec', after '14 déc.'**

An example of a button click that cause the problem:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String s = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM"); // this returns the french abbreviation
    Save();
}
```

I don't have any threads running or code that touches the culture anywhere else. I'm using the latest Entity Framework to handle my data.

I can show more code as needed, though I can't think of anything else that could be relevant.

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.5 or newer? If so try setting `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUiCulture`. The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) explains these new properties.

Comment: @Vache That fixed it, thanks. Post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you aren't explicitly creating new threads, the framework might have done it before calling your event handler.

If you are using .NET 4.5 or newer try setting `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUiCulture`.

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) explains these new properties, but their names are quite self-explanatory.

A new thread's culture defaults to the OS's culture if these properties are not set. [Culture and threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx#Threads) is also an interesting read.